# Why is this site running so bad in Firefox?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Ever since an upgrade a few days ago this Home Improvement site has been running super crappy in FF - all other browsers it is fine.  The site locks up constantly and takes 10-15 seconds to load sometimes.  I am behind a proxy server most of the time so it could be something that is loading through our firewalls quickly, but I don't have any issues with other SE sites and like I said other browsers work fine - checked in IE11, Chrome, Safari.  Anyone else having problems?

I am not really seeing much go on during the hang state.  Right before the hang state I get a console error "The connection to wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com was interrupted...".  It then handles trying to load all of the extensions.  It hangs every time I visit DIY or DIY meta and no other SE sites.  It also hangs every time so not intermittent at all.

Update:  Site is basically unusable in FF (W7 64).  In IE11 it is definitely loading slower than other SE sites but not a huge deal (.5-1 second vs instant).

Another update:

Also another weird behavior was noticed today.  I haven't used site as much lately because of the issues.  But brought it up in IE11 today.  Logged in.  Answered a few questions...  Saw that I had an answer with a comment on another SE site.  Clicked on the other SE site to open in new tab.  Took me to the answer and I am not logged into the site and I didn't see the common "refresh" login bar that I would normally see.  First time this has ever happened.  I suspect that part of the core SE was not uploaded correctly during the last update.

Another update:  As of today FF is responding much better.  Not "fixed" but much much better.  Instead of hanging 10-15 seconds on every load it now hangs 1-2 seconds.  I am assuming something was changed over the past couple days.  But there is still a load issue.

Comment: Fine for me, latest Firefox on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Purely anecdotal but I've observed similar behaviors from Chrome in OSX yesterday.  No proxy server in this scenario.

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug, by adding it as an answer to [this question](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/q/1042/33).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a major issue for a couple months.  If I used FF and Chrome I had major major issues loading the homepage for this site and also the homepage passing on my SE credentials.  I was out of country a few weeks ago but at some point (about a month) this was fixed.

I can't give you the exact date but before I went out of country - mid June - it was definitely still having issues.  At some point over the past month it has been resolved.  I believe it has been working for a few weeks now.  I have waited on purpose to report this because there were times when it seemed to work better for a day or two then reverted back - obviously code changes in the background going on.  Whatever has been done lately, given that is stable, is currently working with no issues.  DIY mods might want to pass this info along.

Answer (score 2):

Some more info:

A profile run when reloading the [newest questions list](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions) shows that 1.7 to 2 seconds is spent in `sidebar/` which calls `d` which calls `f` during which the fps drops to 0:

[image]

version 37.0.2

Comment: I noticed that too but it was across all browsers.   Even in IE and Chrome which work for me the site is noticeably slower than other SE sites.  Also see my new login issue - looks like DIY SE isn't pushing POST data over to other SE sites.